# Is it possible to avoid mutable state using Cucumber-jvm Scala?

Tags: scala, cucumber-jvm

With the Cucumber tests, a feature expressed as `Given`, `When` and `Then` is usually implemented as three separate methods. These methods often need to share values, and this it seems that mutable variables are the way to do it.

Take the following simple example:

A feature:

```
Given the digit 2
When it is multiplied by 3
Then the result is 6
```

And the Cucumber methods:

```
class CucumberRunner extends ScalaDsl with EN with ShouldMatchers {

  var digitUnderTest: Int = -1

  Given("""^the digit (\d)$""") { digit: Int =>
    digitUnderTest = digit
  }

  When("""^it is multiplied by 3$""") {
    digitUnderTest = digitUnderTest * 3
  }

  Then("""^the result is (\d)$""") { result: Int =>
    digitUnderTest should equal (result)
  }
}
```

Is there any way, presumably built into Scala test or Cucumber-jvm for Scala, that allows me not to express `digitUnderTest` as a mutable variable?

Comment: Have you considered using specs2's immutable [Given/When/Then structure](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Structure.html#G%2FW%2FT)?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at `cucumber-jvm` examples in [java](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/examples/java-calculator/src/test/java/cucumber/examples/java/calculator/DateStepdefs.java) and [scala](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/examples/scala-calculator/src/test/scala/cucumber/examples/scalacalculator/RpnCalculatorStepDefinitions.scala), I doubt it provides a way to passing data from step to step without storing it in a variable temporarily.

Since you cannot reassign a `val` in scala, the closest thing I can think of for you to get rid of the mutable `var` is to have a global map that holds temporary test data.

```
class CucumberRunner extends ScalaDsl with EN with ShouldMatchers {

  Given("""^the digit (\d)$""") { digit: Int =>
    GlobalTestData.save("my_unique_key_1", digit)
  }

  When("""^it is multiplied by 3$""") {
    GlobalTestData.load("my_unique_key_1") match {
      case Some(obj) => {
        val result = obj.asInstanceOf[Int] * 3
        GlobalTestData.save("my_unique_key_2", result)
      }
      case None => // throw exception or fail test
    }
  }

  Then("""^the result is (\d)$""") { result: Int =>
    GlobalTestData.load("my_unique_key_2") match {
      case Some(obj) => obj.asInstanceOf[Int] should equal (result)
      case None => // throw exception or fail test
    }
  }
}
```

And then the `GlobalTestData`:

```
object GlobalTestData {
  val map = scala.collection.mutable.Map.empty[String, Any];

  def save(key: String, value: Any) {
    map.put(key, value)
  }

  def load(key: String): Option[Any] = map.get(key)
}
```

In this case, you need to carefully generate keys so they are the same across steps. Of course, you can use some `val`s to hold the values of these keys.

Also in this particular feature, why not combine `Given` and `When` steps:

```
When the digit 2 is multiplied by 3
Then the result is 6
```

This way you can save one slot in `GlobalTestData`.

Comment: Thanks for answering - I did consider something like that, but ideally I don't want anything mutable at all.

Comment: And this feature was just an example, combining Given and When doesn't make much sense for my real steps.

Answer (score 0):

Although in the ScalaDSL for CucumberJVM, a step is a function `f:List[Any] => Any`, the [current implementation](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm-scala/blob/master/scala/sources/src/main/scala/cucumber/runtime/scala/ScalaStepDefinition.scala#L76) discards the results the each step execution, meaning that you have no way to use the result of a previous step in the next one.

Currently, the only way to share the result of one step is through some shared state, either at the step definition class or a more global context like zihaoyu suggested 
(BTW, we use the shared mutable map method as well in a large project)